# Gradle Build Failed - Could not find org.apache.xalan:xalan:2.7.1

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-eclipse

Am trying to build the application using Gradle. Error says "xalan-2.7.1.jar" is required by org.apache.rampart:rampart-core/policy/trust. But it was not loaded.

```
C:\dev\workspace_A_Gradle\a-notification>gradle build

> Configure project :
Current JDK Version --> 1.8

> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.apache.xalan:xalan:2.7.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/xalan/xalan/2.7.1/xalan
-2.7.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/xalan/xalan/2.7.1/xalan
-2.7.1.jar
       - https://artifactory.alight.com/artifactory/list/acd-release-maven-local
/org/apache/xalan/xalan/2.7.1/xalan-2.7.1.pom
       - https://artifactory.alight.com/artifactory/list/acd-release-maven-local
/org/apache/xalan/xalan/2.7.1/xalan-2.7.1.jar
     Required by:
         project :
         project : > org.apache.rampart:rampart-core:1.6.2
         project : > org.apache.rampart:rampart-policy:1.6.2
         project : > org.apache.rampart:rampart-trust:1.6.2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
     url = "https://artifactory.alight.com/artifactory/list/acd-release-maven-local"
    }
}
dependencies {
    //classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.2.RELEASE"
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.1.7.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.6'
    compile 'com.flipkart.zjsonpatch:zjsonpatch:0.4.4'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.6'
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.10.0'
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.10.0'
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.10.0'
    compile 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.25'
    compile 'org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.25'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.9.6'
    compile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.15.0'
    compile 'com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:2.6.2'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    compile 'com.hasbro:hasbro-webservice-util:1.0'
    compile 'com.hasbro:EmployerMgmt:1.0'
    compile 'com.hasbro:PersonMessaging:1.0'
    compile 'com.hewitt.utils:HewittUtil:2.0'
    compile 'org.apache.axis2:axis2-transport-http:1.6.2'
    compile 'org.apache.axis2:axis2-transport-local:1.6.2'
    compile 'org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel:1.6.2'
    compile 'org.apache.axis2:axis2-adb:1.6.2'
    compile 'org.apache.xalan:xalan:2.7.1'
    compile 'xalan:serializer:2.7.1'
    compile 'org.apache.rampart:rampart-core:1.6.2'
    compile 'org.apache.rampart:rampart-policy:1.6.2'
    compile 'org.apache.rampart:rampart-trust:1.6.2'
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.1.2.RELEASE'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.0'
}
```

I saw that Gradle automatically downloaded xalan-2.7.1.jar. I don't know how to fix this bug.

Comment: module  `org.apache.xalan:xalan:2.7.1` is not  available in standard public Maven repositories (see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xalan/xalan/2.7.1 ). You should use `xalan:xalan:2.7.1` instead.

Comment: Thank you @M.Ricciuti! Tried like this - dependencies { compile 'xalan:xalan:2.7.1' }. 
I have tried xalan:xalan:2.7.1 as well. Am getting same error.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
 > Could not find org.apache.xalan:xalan:2.7.1.

Please let me know need to mention any specific maven URL under repositories tag?

Comment: from your error log we see that you still have a dependency to `org.apache.xalan:xalan:2.7.1`, maybe from transitive dependencies . Please execute `./gradlew dependencies` and search in the Gradle output, where is this `org.apache.xalan:xalan:2.7.1` coming from (which other library from your project has this transitive dependency):  then try to exclude this library using Gradle exclusions.

Comment: @M.Ricciuti -    It was trying to read xalan from maven2, but it was not found.
> Could not find org.apache.xalan:xalan:2.7.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/xalan/xalan/2.7.1/xalan
-2.7.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/xalan/xalan/2.7.1/xalan
-2.7.1.jar
     Required by:
         project : > org.apache.rampart:rampart-core:1.6.2
         project : > org.apache.rampart:rampart-policy:1.6.2
         project : > org.apache.rampart:rampart-trust:1.6.2

Same error in ./gradlew as well.

Comment: If we added the xalan jars in our own repositories, then this will solve this error?

Comment: please read my comment above: you should exclude this lib from the transitive dependencies, using `./gradlew dependencies` command to locate which module is bringing this dependency in your project. adding this lib in your own repo is not recommanded.

Comment: Its worked @M.Ricciuti. Thank you!
Updated gradle.build:
 configurations {
 all*.exclude module: 'xalan'
}

 compile('org.apache.rampart:rampart-core:1.6.2') { 
        exclude group: 'xalan'
    }
    compile('org.apache.rampart:rampart-policy:1.6.2') { 
        exclude group: 'xalan'
    }
    compile('org.apache.rampart:rampart-trust:1.6.2') { 
        exclude group: 'xalan'
    }

Answer (score 0):

Adding below will solve the problem
implementation group: 'xalan', name: 'xalan', version: '2.7.3'
implementation group: 'xalan', name: 'serializer', version: '2.7.3'